# Global Agenda Quest Lines

Tags: global-agenda

I recently picked up Global Agenda in a Steam sale. I was going along enjoying the quest line with some friends when suddenly the quest line just drops off the face of the desert.

Am I missing something?

I mean, I have no problem just doing the pvp / pve missions the rest of the time, but it's just odd being dropped like a hot tamale at level 17 out of what seems to be a potential 50.

Edit: The quests completed is "Beyond Life and Death", followed by "Cured!". Though, after reading Raven Dreamer's comment, I've gotten the feeling that it's the (current) end of the line.

Comment: It might help to include which quest you finished. Don't forget, however, that open-world PvE content are relatively new for Global Agenda, only being added in the Sandstorm patch -- there's not going to be enough PvE content to reach level 30.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer Oh, really? I was not aware of this... That actually explains a lot.

Comment: yeah, the original plan was always to have players level up through the instanced PvE or PvP missions. When the players were asked for more traditional PvE, HiRez eventually added it in.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I see. Well that certainly does explain a lot. Thank you muchly! If you wish to make this an answer, I'll most definitely accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to include which quest you finished. Don't forget, however, that open-world PvE content is relatively new for Global Agenda, only having being added in the Sandstorm patch -- there's not going to be enough PvE content to reach level 30 through open-world PvE alone.

The original plan was always to have players level up through the instanced PvE or PvP missions. When the players were asked for more traditional PvE, HiRez eventually added it in.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in the game. When you get to the wasps on the first desert, the man on the tower is invisible, so you need to just activate the conversation on the spot where the character should be. This happens in a few later missions too. Also, you need to go back to do the pit mission in this area.